# How to ensure authenticity of sync target in WiFi network (do not run sync outside of home WiFi)

Tags: encryption, home-networking, http, authentication, smb

This is my first question and I hope to explain the situation well.

**Short explanation:**

I have a home network with various clients and a TrueNAS NAS. The NAS is target for backup and sync services e.g. using SMB and HTTP and addressed by its private network IP.

- How can I make sure that the tasks only run in my own home WiFi and not in some other network to prevent my data being shared when I use mobile devices somewhere else?
- In other words: how high is the risk that e.g. my smartphone connects to the same IP (that the NAS has in my home WiFi) in some other network so that someone malicious could obtain data or credentials?
- How can my clients be sure that they are connected to the correct target (the NAS) in a WiFi network?

I am thankful for any tips and pointers.

---

**More detailed explanation:**

Currently, the NAS is addressed by its local IP (192.168.xxx.xxx) and accessed by Android (>= 10) and Windows (10/11) clients. In the home network, encryption of traffic is not necessary.

What I have found so far:

- On Android, apps sometimes support to run in WiFi networks with specific SSIDs only (e.g. [FolderSync](https://foldersync.io/)). From [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/is-hacking-wi-fi-that-easy-just-spoof-and-its-hacked), faking an SSID on WPA2 seems hard (WPA3 should be more secure), so the problem should be solved for these apps. However, not all the apps that I use support that.
- I use Syncthing, which creates a unique key-pair and certificate per device for encrypted sync between devices, so Syncthing traffic should be fine as well.
- Self-signed certificates could be an option. I think that I would have to add them to all my devices, but I am not sure if these certificates are supported by all the clients/apps.
- Because all NAS services run on the same IP, I could maybe add some layer between the clients and the NAS that performs the authentication for all traffic.

Has anyone faced the same problem in his/her own home network? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a complicated question to me. Put a VERY strong password on your wireless.  Not hard to make a password strong enough to require someone outside your network to spend 200,000 years of constant hacking to get in. If you wish to allow guests in, make a VLAN for them.

Comment: If your tasks connect to `192.168.xxx.xxx`, this is only possible inside your local network. Outside of it, connection will fail.

Comment: Doesn't modern SMB always require two-way (bidirectional) authentication? If not, wouldn't somebody be screaming about how insecure it is?

Comment: At first glance this is non issue. Whether or not it gets the same *internal* IP in a different network is immaterial and totally irrelevant for the possibility of accessing your home NAS.

Comment: Sync over SSH, which will take care of your requirements.

Comment: @Spiff if SMB uses two way authentication (client can be sure that it talks to the genuine Server), SMB traffic should be fine. I could not find much info on that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you are right. I am more concerned about the risk of someone faking my NAS services in his/her own network and my clients connecting to it.

Comment: @Spiff: most Android/iOS apps only barely use modern SMB (well, arguably SMBv2 is modern but that's the _bare minimum_), but unfortunately, no, even with latest SMBv3.x you still have no meaningful 'server identity' as long as you're using NTLM auth, and that's what literally every app is still stuck with. Either SMB with Kerberos or SMB over QUIC would solve this problem, with the former being already easy to set up on Windows... but it'll probably take 1000 more years for android file managers to get support for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring the authenticity of the server is dependent on the application and protocol used:

- HTTP: purchase a domain and map the domain name in the DNS to your local IP. Then obtain an SSL-Certificate for the domain and install it on your server. Use the domain name via HTTPS as a target on the clients. This way, only your server (with the certificate) will be trusted by the clients, even if the same local IP exists in a different network. You can also use a reverse proxy on the server for apps not supporting HTTPS.
- Syncthing: already TLS-based; above approach can be used for admin web interface
- SMB: (see comment by u1686_grawity) SMBv2/SMBv3 do not authenticate the server. Server authentication is possible with Kerberos or SMB over QUIC protocol, but mobile apps usually don't support either.

Also, for mobile devices, you can sometimes restrict apps to run in specific WiFi networks only.